# How to deal with DataAnnotations attributes in ASP.NET Web API on string.Empty values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, validation, asp.net-web-api

I struggle with the usage of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` validation attributes in ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET MVC with `string.Empty` or `null` values. What would you recommend is the best practice to deal with this when using JSON data?

Consider the following Model

```
    public class SampleModel
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you can observe the following behavior in `Web Api` and `MVC`:

```
    (1) API: { "Foo": null } => Foo == null
    (2) API: { "Foo": "" } => Foo == ""
    (3) MVC: { "Foo": null } => Foo == null
    (4) MVC: { "Foo": "" } => Foo == null
```

Note: The last conversion (4) is due to the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` parameter.

Now, consider  the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` validation attribute usage:

```
    public class SampleModel
    {
        [RangeAttribute(0, 9)]
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
```

The `ModelState.IsValid` check returns `true` in all 4 cases, even though `""` is obviously not in range `[0..9]`, because all validation attributes check for string.IsNullOrEmpty. Now one could argument that `null` as well as `string.Empty` can be considered as optional, but especially in Web API due to the lack of the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` parameter IMHO this is not correct. In my opinion, in Web API an optional element (like `Foo`) is only optional if it is missing or has a `null` value. And `string.Empty` is a particular value. Thus, we can't use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` validation attributes 1:1.

How do you deal with that issue, what is best practice and what is the intention of the ASP.NET team? Do we have to inherit from all `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` validation attributes? Do we have use our own attributes in Web API for validation or do we have to write own `ModelMetadataProviders`?

PS: just to clearify... the `string.Empty` and `null` value handling in the model binders is ok for me.

Comment: There is a string boolean method which might assist: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)`

Comment: In which case this method helps me? Above I did not check anything outside the default attributes.